# Providing a complete table of results regardless of whether records exist

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Say I have a 'Master' dataset which is being used to produce a multitude of tables, all which have their own additional filtering and grouping appied to them. The 'Master' dataset contains around 30 columns one of which is 'SL', the below table makes use of this column and counts the number of records within the 'Master' dataset to produce totals grouped by dates.

[image]

My Question is, Say there are two other 'SLs' which are type 'A' and 'Unspecified' how might I include rows for them, regardless of whether the 'Master' dataset contains records which are marked under that type, and the totals would naturally be ZERO for the three dates.

I can produce an additional dataset which lists all the types by simply doing :

```
select distinct type_sl
from [mytable]
```

But I am unable to drag and drop this into my existing table as it is part of a different dataset, I also dont see how I would alter my existing dataset to include rows for these types as the rest of the data would be NULL, or is this the way do to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with your suggestion, i.e. adjusting your Dataset to always include these SL values, even if everything else is `NULL`.

i.e. assuming the Dataset is generated from a T-SQL query, use `[mytable]` as the base table and LEFT JOIN back to this as required.

You can use `IsNothing` in the report expression to replace `NULL` values with *0* if required.

Another approach is to use a table with a set number of rows for all required SL values, instead of relying on the required columns being dynamically generated by a tablix type object, and then filling the columns' values with appropriate conditional expressions, e.g. for the *B* column use something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!type_sl.Value = "B", Fields!MyValue.Value, Nothing)
```

However, I would lean toward the first option - the main advantages being you can still maintain the existing structure, i.e. dynamic grouping to increase the number of rows as required, and the fact that you only have to change the underlying database code to have the change applied to all items that use that database code.